# g group element doesn't start at 0,0 inside the svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, svelte

I am trying d3.js with svelte, and I started to do a simple bar chart, but I am facing an issue I couldn't figure out. The issue, is, the group element `g` inside the `svg` element, that contains the bars, is initially shifted from the origin of the `svg` element (the top left corner). This is the code

```
<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3';
  let data = [
    { name: 'Apple', amount: 20 },
    { name: 'Orange', amount: 80 },
    { name: 'Banana', amount: 50 },
    { name: 'Grapes', amount: 10 },
  ];

  let width = 600;
  let height = 400;

  let margins = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100 };

  let innerWidth = width - margins.left - margins.right;
  let innerHeight = height - margins.top - margins.bottom;

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((d) => d.name))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .paddingInner(0.1);
  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.amount)])
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);
</script>

<div class="canvas">
  <svg {width} {height}>
    <g>
      {#each data as d}
        <rect
          width={xScale.bandwidth()}
          height={innerHeight - yScale(d.amount)}
          x={xScale(d.name) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}
          y={yScale(d.amount)}
        />
      {/each}
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<style>
  .canvas {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

I was expecting the group element `g` to start at `(0,0)` of the `svg` element (the top left corner), but it's x-shifted without any `transform` attribute on the `g` element. This is messing things up when I try to shift the group element appropriately to add axes later. My question is: why is there initial shift?

Here are the `svg` and `g` elements as appear on the screen

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `g` is not translated, the bounds of the `g` merely reflect the bounds of its contents. If the contents aren't bounded by a point at [0,0], the `g` also won't be bounded by a point at [0,0].

Eyeballing it, I'd say the left most limit of the bars, and therefore the `g`, is about half the bandwidth from the edge of the SVG. If we look at how you position the bars, that makes sense:

```
 x={xScale(d.name) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}
```

Despite a scaled value of 0 for the first bar, the rectangle is nudged over by half the bandwidth. The placement of the `g` just reflects the placement of the bars, not a transform.

Comment: You are right. I haven't worked with d3 for a while, and I remember using `+xScale.bandwidth()/2` for the `x` attribute, but now I know it was for the labels to position them at the center of the bars, and not for the bars themselves. Removing it fixed the problem. Thank you